# I cannot import by package here. I am using Selenium 4.x

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import by
serv_obj=Service("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj)

driver.get("https://www.testyou.in/Login.aspx")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.NAME,"ctl00$CPHContainer$txtUserLogin").send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
```

Web page is successfully launching but its showing import error like this:

> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import by
> ImportError: cannot import name 'by' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.by' (C:\Users\HP\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\by.py)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `By` there , as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```